# How to iterate two lists with just one for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given two random size lists, how can I extract items from both of them using just one `for` loop? The precondition is that besides the functions you can see in the example below only `math.floor` and `math.ceil` are available, hence no `enumerate`, `zip`, no `if` statements or similar helpers.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
xy = len(x) * len(y)

for i in range(xy):
    xi = x[ceil((xy - i)/len(y)) - 1]
    yi = '?'
    print(i, xi, yi)

0 3 ?
1 3 ?
2 3 ?
3 3 ?
4 2 ?
5 2 ?
6 2 ?
7 2 ?
8 1 ?
9 1 ?
10 1 ?
11 1 ?
```

Desired output:

```
0 1 a
1 1 b
2 1 c
3 1 d
4 2 a
5 2 b
6 2 c
7 2 d
8 3 a
9 3 b
10 3 c
11 3 d
```

Comment: Explain your precondition. Why no `zip`? If you deliberately avoid the natural Pythonic solution, then a Pythonic solution is not to be expected. Neither `math.floor` nor `math.ceil` are obviously relevant. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnColeman It's logical question, not necessarily specific to python. But I'm most familiar with python, hence the tags.

Comment: You can't use two for loops?

Comment: If you don't want to use things like `itertool.product`, just use nested for loops.

Comment: *"only `math.floor` and `math.ceil` functions are available"* - but you use `print`, `range`, and `len` in your example...

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Correct, only one `for` loop.

Comment: You need to explain just what the "preconditions" are, rather than introducing them in an ad-hoc fashion in response to natural solutions.

Comment: Can any assumptions be made about the values in `x`? Such as the values in `x` will be less than `len(y)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman See edited question.

Comment: @NarūnasK That helps, although the questions still seems like it requires reading the mind of some unknown professor who is in the habit of making arbitrary homework assignments (something I am probably guilty of myself).

Comment: Can you use `try/except`? This is almost an impossible solution with your edge cases.  It could be done with a double `for` or a `for` with an `if` but with you edge cases its near impossible.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Nope, only the things you can see in the given example .

Comment: And no assumptions can be made about the contents of the lists? Not even that they are in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `math.floor`, nothing else:

```
from math import floor

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
xy = len(x) * len(y)

for i in range(xy):
    xi = x[floor(i/len(y))]
    yi = y[i - floor(i/len(y))*len(y)]
    print(i, xi, yi)

0 1 a
1 1 b
2 1 c
3 1 d
4 2 a
5 2 b
6 2 c
7 2 d
8 3 a
9 3 b
10 3 c
11 3 d
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you *should* do this is use itertools, and take a [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (named for the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) between your lists. Note that you can use enumerate to get the index and elements of an [`iterator`](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) while iterating.

```
import itertools

for i, (f, s) in enumerate(itertools.product(x, y)):
    print(i, f, s)
```

Under the constraints of the questions.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i in range(len(x)*len(y)):
    f = x[i % len(x)]
    s = y[i // len(x)]
    print(i, f, s)
```

giving

```
0 1 a
1 2 a
2 3 a
3 4 a
4 1 b
5 2 b
6 3 b
7 4 b
8 1 c
9 2 c
10 3 c
11 4 c
```

and because you claim to not be allowed to use modulo or integer division how about

```
import math

for i in range(len(x)*len(y)):
    idx_s = math.floor(i / len(x))
    f = x[i - idx_s*len(x)]
    s = y[idx_s]
    print(i, f, s)
```

I am not sure why you think you need `ceil` and `floor` to do this. If you are going to import anything, import itertools. Otherwise, just do something like the above

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, only `math.floor` and `math.ceil` are available. Basically only the functions you see in the example in the question.

Comment: modified @NarūnasK

Comment: Can you translate `%` and `//` into `math.floor` and `math.ceil` expressions?

Comment: @NarūnasK What do you mean, only `math.floor` and `math.ceil`? You are also using `len`, `*`, and so on. I think the restriction is only on library funcitons, but `%` and `//` are basic python operators, like `*`, so those should be allowed, too.

Comment: @tobias_k is right - it would be a silly assignment to not be able to use binary operators. But sure, I can get rid of `//` and `%`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), the inner generator returns a pairwise cartesian product which we simply make use of while looping.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for index, (item1, item2) in enumerate(((i, j) for i in x for j in y)):
    print (f"{index} {item1} {item2}")
```

Outputting:

```
0 1 a
1 1 b
2 1 c
3 1 d
4 2 a
5 2 b
6 2 c
7 2 d
8 3 a
9 3 b
10 3 c
11 3 d
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it would be something like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
xy = len(x) * len(y)

counter = 1
for i in range(xy):
  internal_index = i % len(y)
  if internal_index == 0:
    counter++
  xi = counter 
  yi = '?'
  print(i, xi, y[internal_index])
```

No 100% sure if this works did it from the top of my head but the I guest you get the idea :).